# How to remove Square brackets using preg_split()?

Tags: php

I have this expression:

```
The Exorcist's [Restored Version] (xvid110-sickboy88)
```

And want output like this :

```
The Exorcist's Restored Version xvid110 sickboy88
```

Please help thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think that `preg_split()` is the way to go about this...

Comment: surely all you need for removing all those brackets is $string = str_replace(array('[',']','(',')'),'',$string);

Answer (score 6):

No need for regular expressions. [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/function.str-replace.php) will do the job. If its first parameter is an array but the second is a string, all elements of the first array will be replaced by the second string parameter.

```
$input = "The Exorcist's [Restored Version] (xvid110-sickboy88)";
$str = str_replace(array("[", "]", "(", ")"), "", $input);
echo $str;

// The Exorcist's Restored Version xvid110-sickboy88
```

Comment: +1. Right tool for the right job. No need to nuke a building because there's a fly in one of the rooms.

Answer (score 2):

```
       $string = "The Exorcist's [Restored Version] (xvid110-sickboy88)";
       $simbols = array("[", "]", "(", ")");
       echo str_replace($simbols , "", $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this is working........
use before middle squire brackets forward slashes **

$keywords = preg_split("/[[]]/", "[hypertext] language, programming");

print_r($keywords);